# Custom Role Permission to allow read on Azure storage account Queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-queues, azure-rbac

User has been assigned a custom role with below Actions on an Azure storage account but user sees `This request is not authorized to perform this operation`:

```
{
    "id": ..,
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "ContributorBPMD(custom)",
        "description": ..
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/XXX"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "notActions": [
                    "notActions": [
                    ...
                    "Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules/write",
                    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/delete",
                    "Microsoft.Storage/locations/deleteVirtualNetworkOrSubnets/action",
                    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/privateEndpointConnections/delete",
                    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/privateEndpointConnections/write",
                    ...
                ],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't see any not allowed actions for `Microsoft.storageAccounts/queueServices/*`.
What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the user is getting this error is because reading from queue is a data plane operation and no permissions are defined in `dataActions` in the custom role.

Simplest way to solve this problem would be to assign [`Storage Queue Data Reader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-queue-data-reader) role to the user or add `"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/messages/read"` permission in `dataActions` in the custom role.